# nlsTracePlot returns "is not a function" - how to solve this issue?(R)

Tags: r, nls

I have a dataframe, with

```
### create sample data
set.seed(1)
x = runif(n = 100, 0, 20)
beta1 = 2
beta2 = 1
beta3 = (1/2)

### Create sample data frame and vector
y = beta1 + beta2*x^(beta3) + rnorm(n = 100, 0, 0.01)
 data = as.data.frame(cbind(y,x))

 ### Fitting the data with nls()-function;
 fit1 = nls(
 y~vb1(x,beta1,beta2,beta3),
 data=data,start=list(beta1 = 0, beta2 = 1, beta3 = 1)
)
```

where

```
 vb1 = function(x,beta1,beta2,beta3){
   beta1 + beta2*x^(beta3)
 }
```

In the end I want to plot the output:

```
 plot(y~x, col = 3)
 nlsTracePlot(fit1,vb1(x,beta1,beta2,beta3),legend="bottomright")
```

However, it gives the following error,

> ```
>  3. stop(gettextf("'%s' is not a function, character or symbol",           deparse(FUN)), domain = NA)
>  2. match.fun(fun)
>  1. nlsTracePlot(fit1, vb1(x, beta1, beta2, beta3), legend = "bottomright")
> ```

Everything works just fine, until I try to plot it with the above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `FSA` package, you will need to pass the `fun` argument a raw function. The function needs to be specified in a particular way. See documentation of `nlsTracePlot` for more information.

```
vb1 <- function(x, beta1, beta2, beta3){
  if (length(beta1) == 3) {
    beta2 <- beta1[2]
    beta3 <- beta1[3]
    beta1 <- beta1[1]
  }
  beta1 + beta2 * x^(beta3)
}

plot(y ~ x, col = 3)
nlsTracePlot(fit1, vb1, legend = "bottomright")
```

[image]

Comment: This is really interesting! I will give it a try - I highly appreciate your answer.

Comment: I implemented your solution, and it worked like a charm. After 3 hours of trying to solve it, its done! Thank you so much!

There is a few things that I do not understand, which I would hope you could clarify;

Firstly, what is it that the if else function does, that if its omitted, the function fails?

Secondly, I count 7 lines, but NLS finished after 6 iterations. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Kartal1903 6 + initial iteration with starting parameters is 7 lines, I reckon?